# Get Uuids from BLE Device

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy

I want to get all Uuids from a BLE Device I discovered with the following code:

```
public class DiscoverLe : ScanCallback
{
   public DiscoverLe()
   {
   }

   public override void OnScanResult([GeneratedEnum] ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
   {
      base.OnScanResult(callbackType, result);                
      ScanRecord oScanRecord = result.ScanRecord;
      byte[] oByteArray =  result.ScanRecord.GetManufacturerSpecificData(76);                          
   }
}
```

Can somebody please explain how to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest you to read Bluetooth Version 4.0 specs. If you mean *UUID*s of the services and characteristics, unfortunately you can't do it without connecting to remote device and starting Service Discovery Procedure. BLE Advertisement Data can hold up to 31 bytes data. Please read the following [link](http://www.argenox.com/bluetooth-low-energy-ble-v4-0-development/library/a-ble-advertising-primer/) and figure out how BLE advertising packets are structured. The remote BLE device that you discovered might include some of the Service UUID data (The UUID can be 2 bytes or 8 bytes. Thus, don't expect to see all the service UUIDs). It is the vendor's choice to include service UUIDs in advertisement packets or not. However, you can never ever get Characteristic UUID information without establishing BLE connection and performing service discovery.